# Using typings.d.ts in Angular library without tripple-slash reference

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, ng-packagr

Within an Angular CLI workspace, I created a library `foo`. Within library `foo`, I added a `typings.d.ts` file. I then managed to reference a type defined in `typings.d.ts` from `foo.module.ts` using the [Typescript triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).  Now, I would like to not have to use the triple-slash directive but removing the directive results in the following error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyLibrary'.
```

I am a bit surprised that I am receiving this error because `typings.d.ts` is defined within the `src` directory and I am using a recent version of Typescript (v3.2.4). I therefore expected the compiler to pick up `typings.d.ts` out of the box. I also tried adding the following to `tsconfig.lib.json`:

```
"include": [
  "src/typings.d.ts"
]
```

I expected that at least this setting would take effect because the ng-packagr docs mention that [within an Angular CLI project the tsconfig.lib.json file may be amended](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/override-tsconfig.md#angular-cli-users).

So, my specific question is the following: 
Is it possible to reference types from a `typings.d.ts` file within an Angular library without needing to use triple-slash references? If no, then why?

My sandbox is [here](https://github.com/samherrmann/angular-sandbox/blob/library-global-type-definition/projects/foo/src/lib/foo.module.ts#L1).

## Relevant Resources

- [angular.io - Defining typings for runtime-global libraries](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#defining-typings-for-runtime-global-libraries)
- [ng-packagr - How to add custom typings to a library build?](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/193#issuecomment-338009572)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Managed to fix this by removing the `d.ts` affix from the typings path.